# ¿Por qué en la consulta de la línea 13 da el error que se muestra en la imagen mientras que en la 14 funciona bien?

Tags: plpgsql

declare
fila record;
begin
for fila in select distinct(id_father) from padre_hijo
loop
create view hermanos as select id_son from padre_hijo where id_father = fila.id_father;
--raise notice 'padre id: %', fila.id_father;
end loop;

end;
$BODY$;[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sabemos que creará un view en cada iteración del ciclo pero primero necesito que funcione la consulta

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para agregar más detalles a tu pregunta, y no olvides que el código debe ir _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.